# A quick and convenient way to attach photos

Tags: workflow, photos

There is an application with which engineers check equipment. Engineers photograph equipment before and after testing. The application looks something like this:

[image: Two buttons for capturing "before" image, and capturing "after" image]

The user would have to:

1. Click the add photo before button.
2. Take a picture.
3. Click the add photo button after.
4. Take a picture.

In my opinion, this is not very convenient and takes a long time.

Are there any other solutions that will shorten the time it takes to add photos?

Comment: What problems do you see with this solution? It seems like that workflow is already quite lean. You mention only two taps to capture each picture (open camera, capture picture). That seems like pretty much the minimum possible to me.

Comment: Could you please describe how you achieve with this app that engineer doesn't forget to take picture before checking equipment? This could help to answer your question.

Comment: Photo, this is a prerequisite for checking equipment. Without a photo, the task will not close